# How to open a RSS link in Safari for iOS App by my own RSS Reader?

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari

I develop a RSS reader App named "iRead", What cloud I do to make open the the RSS Link by launching my App when I open a RSS Link in Safari for iOS，and Safari App recognizes it is a RSS Link. The Condition now is that Safari warn "Can't open the page, this is a RSS Feed Link...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know you can't. iOS is not Android, where you can select the default app to open something. You can create a Share Extension, so when the user selects to share the RSS Link URL, your app handle the link.

Comment: np. If you want some help with SE, you can talk with me. (: